# POST error with Sinatra with JSON

Tags: ruby, json, post, curl, sinatra

I'm learning Ruby + Sinatra, and found a good post [here](http://alfuken.tumblr.com/post/874428235/upload-and-download-files-in-sinatra) which talks about how to upload files.

```
post '/upload/:filename' do
  userdir = "./upload"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(userdir) unless File.exists?(userdir)
  filename = File.join(userdir, params[:filename])
  datafile = params[:data]
  File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(datafile[:tempfile].read)
  end
end
```

I can use the following cURL command to upload files fine.

```
curl -v -F "data=@/Users/me/Desktop/test.pdf"  http://localhost:4567/upload/test.pdf
```

But now I had decided to use JSON to handle all incoming/outgoing responses.  I tried this, but it didn't seem to work.

```
curl -i -X POST -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{file:{filename:"test.pdf",md5sum:"ab3d2f"}}'  --data-binary @/Users/me/Desktop/test.pdf 'http://localhost:4567/upload/test.pdf'
```

I also received an error like this:

```
NoMethodError at /upload/test.pdf
undefined method `get' for #<WebTest:0x101374dd8>
file: web.rb location: POST /upload/:filename line: 48
```

What should I do now?

**Edited:**

Line 48 is this `file.write(datafile[:tempfile].read`

Please help!

Comment: you need to debug. first, I would determine which line is line 48.

Comment: According to Sinatra, it's definitely how it uses 'route' for POST.
Unless I miss something here.

Comment: And why would I care about "GET" here because I only need to construct a POST method. And will only use a POST method.

Comment: Thanks! I'm here to get help, but I may not have a good question, but I definitely looking for an answer or some advices. I'm new to Sinatra and Ruby, and always eager to learn. I just have some design questions which are hard to put it clearly.  Because there's no 1 way to do things, which is why I need to learn from you guys.

I still have no idea why this has errors. Yes. I used warn/puts to debug as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting your second curl command to do, but I'm pretty sure it's not doing what you want. If you give more than one `--data` or `-d` parameters to curl, their values will be joined together, separated by `&`.

For example, if you have a file `test.txt` with contents `This is a test.` and you do request like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json \
    -d '{file:{filename:"test.txt",md5sum:"ab3d2f"}}'                  \
    --data-binary @test.txt 'http://localhost:4567/upload/test.txt'
```

This is what the request looks like:

```
POST /upload/test.txt HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Host: localhost:4567
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 61

{file:{filename:"test.txt",md5sum:"ab3d2f"}}&This is a test.
```

The request body is not valid JSON. It's not valid URL-encoded form data or multi-part form data either.

It's not obvious how to combine JSON requests with file uploads. Here are some options:

- Just use `multipart/form-data`. That is, do what you're doing right now with your Ruby code and `-F` option to curl.
- Use `multipart/form-data` with one part of JSON for metadata and other part with the raw uploaded file.
- Embed the file into JSON by base64-encoding it.
- Do some kind of two-request workflow where first you post the metadata as JSON and then you upload the file in the POST body.

I'd probably go with the first option, because it's so widely supported.

Comment: Thanks! That's a helpful answer!
I'm using the first option, but it only supports uploading 1 binary file. If I also want to POST both the file AND the JSON content (which includes the MD5sum of that file), how do I post it? 

I haven't seen an example online for that.

Comment: You can have "form fields" for the other data. `curl -F 'md5sum=ab3d2f` -F 'data=@test.pdf' http://...` and then access it with `params[:md5sum]` in Ruby. You could also just post a JSON object  that way. `curl -F 'json={file: {filename: "test.txt",md5sum: "ab3d2f"}}' ...` and then decode it in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I transfer file embedded using JSON object way?

Comment: Essentially you'd have to base64-encode the file or otherwise convert it into JSON-safe format so you can put it in there as a string. This can't be done with just curl alone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your Ruby code is broken; you forgot an `end`:

```
post '/upload/:filename' do
  userdir = "./upload"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(userdir) unless File.exists?(userdir)
  filename = File.join(userdir, params[:filename])
  datafile = params[:data]
  File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(datafile[:tempfile].read)
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually had that, but just didn't copy and paste right. Still not able to get this running with the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can get it working with the below curl command with JSON:

```
curl -v -F 'json=[ {"filename": "@/Users/me/Desktop/test.pdf", "md5sum": "1496f9b6f42b7ed8260eadeb158c33f4", type": "generic"}, {"filename": "@/Users/me/Desktop/test2.pdf", "md5sum": "1496f9b6f42b7ed8260eadeb158c33f4", type": "generic"} ]' http://localhost:4567/upload
```

However, since I don't use `-F 'file=@/Users/me/Desktop/test.pdf'` to POST my file, how do I retrieve the file on the server-side using JSON objects?

The below is no longer working.

```
tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile]
filename = params[:file][:filename]
dest = "#{userdir}/#{filename}"
FileUtils.cp(tempfile.path, dest) if not File.exists?(dest)
```

Comment: If you aren't using the `-F 'file=@test.pdf', the file isn't included in the request and this can't be done.

Comment: I was thinking about passing multiple files in the POST request. What are some other ways we can do this?

Comment: @xbeta Answers are answers, questions are questions. This should either be an update to the question, or the extra info in here should be in a new question. Also "Now I can get it working" is meaningless. Try `warn params.keys.inspect` and see what you're receiving now, as it looks to me like you're sending an array of hashes now, accessing by key like you have been won't work.

Comment: I had already stated that my new cURL command had it working. It's probably I didn't have a correct syntax at the beginning. So this is OK now. 


Thanks for your concern.  I still want to know if we can pass multiple files in the POST request.  

I'm here to learn, so I may not have the proper terms to ask question spot on, but I thought Stackoverflow encourage people to learn, and have mercy on the newbies.